# WF4 Rules engine design and performance

Tags: .net, performance, workflow-foundation, rules

I'am designing Business Rules Validation engine and I had choose WF Rules Engine as a basis.
Currently I need to decide if it's a good thing to give DB access through Rules Engine to business users.

From one point, it's might be very powerful, since I even can give ability to write queries and use procedures in DB directly in Rules editor. From other point I afraid that the performance of such design may be very slow.

First I thought to use Generics, so it would be easy create different data objects for rules validation, but since WF4 not support the Generic classes (at least I didn't found a way), I thinking about other way to make workflow "Generic" and do not create specific workflow with data that the rules needs to.

So the main questions are:
1) Is it good to use SQL queries in Rules
2) What other options I have, to make rules workflow Generic?

Thank you.